# error in deserialization using JSON.net

Tags: c#, json, multithreading, linq, json.net

i am using the **JSON.net serialization/deserialization** in my **c#** application.
it was working fine when suddenly it brang the below error in `ErrorOnDeserialization`;
What can i do to resolve it?

the error is as below:

```
CurrentObject:{System.Threading.Thread}
ErrorContext:
{
Error:{"Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type 'System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.LogicalCallContext'."}
Member:"ExecutionContext"
Path:"Dispatcher.Thread.ExecutionContext"
}
```

i have uploaded a sample project in below link. please run it and open the .flow file in it until it gets in the break point which shows the error.
[enter link description here](http://uploadboy.me/y8fxek15xscd/j.rar.html)

Comment: @May be this problem occurs due to add some reference.Do u add Newtonsoft.Json.dll reference?

Comment: @anisprogrammer - hi. yes i am using Newtonsoft.Json.dll and it has been added to the refrences of the project!

Comment: Could you please show me your code

Comment: Your json and your object don't match. Please post the class that  you have, a sample json and the deserialization code

Comment: @anisprogrammer - the code is very huge!more than 25000 lines. if you can tell me that what portion of the code do you need?

Comment: @Emad - i have added the sample project

Comment: dont have any solution?

Comment: @dbc - do you have any idea?

Comment: Link is broken. This question is of nu use any more. Make sure you always add the relevant code to the question text.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are trying to deserialize system.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.LogicalCallContext that was 
created on a specific machine in a specific context to another machine in a different context.

The deserialization failing due do a different structure of the object properties.

There is no reason, that I can think of, for anyone trying to serialize/deserialize that kind of object, and you are probably doing that unintentionally when you serialize all your class's fields, **which causing the serialization of all the classes you inherited from**, one of them is a system class with the field system.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.LogicalCallContext.

To solve your problem, *and to improve your performance*, I suggest using **[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]** attribute, adding it on your failing to serialize class - to control which members and DataMembers will be serialize/deserialize, by adding [JsonProperty] attribute only on the members that you really need.